# Ruby Axlsx how to add row with merged cells

Tags: ruby, excel, axlsx

I want to generate the below excel:
[image]

I tried bellow code

```
row = [1, 2, [31, 32]]
p = Axlsx::Package.new
wb = p.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Sheet1") do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row row
end
```

But I get the bellow result

|column1|column2| column3 |

|   1   |   2   | [31, 32]|

Answer (score 2):

axlsx cell merging cannot be performed during row insertion.

What you want to do here is insert row 1 using [1, 2, 31] and row 2 using [nil, nil, 32] and then perform your merging after insert.

Have a look at the example:

```
require 'axlsx'
package = Axlsx::Package.new
package.workbook do |workbook|
  workbook.add_worksheet name: 'merged_cells' do |sheet|
    4.times do
      sheet.add_row %w(a b c d e f g)
    end
    sheet.merge_cells "A1:A2"
    sheet.merge_cells "B1:B2"
  end
end
```

https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/examples/merge_cells.rb

It will likely get you most of the way there.

Comment: In my situation, I need to insert dynamic rows

`[1, 2, [31, 32]]`, 
`[1, 2, [31, 32, 33]]`, 
`[1, 2]`, is easy to do it